# NSPredicate: Filter objects based on property of custom NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nspredicate, key-value-coding

I'm using the following `SampleClass` containing a custom `NSObject` inside

```
public class SampleClass: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged public var string: NSString?
@NSManaged public var object: NSObject?

...
}
```

I want to filter the objects based on a property of the `NSObject` inside the `SampleClass` using `NSPredicate`. So I tried the following:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"object.someProperty CONTAINS[c] %@", filterString)
```

Unfortunately this produces a crash throwing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` Error.

Is it even possible to use `NSPredicate` for this operation?

Comment: What API are you trying to use the predicate in? ie something like NSArray's filteredArrayUsingPredicate?

Comment: I want to use NSFetchRequest to fetch CoreData

Comment: update your predicate code with this.  let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"self.NAME_OF_YOUR_PROPERTY CONTAINS[c] %@", filterString)